# Rails: How to update associated data on load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to update associated data on load in Rails 3.x?

When I load a stock symbol, I would like to update its quotes if they are outdated. Since ActiveRecord does not have a callback like after_load, what is the right way to do this?

My pseudo code looks like

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quotes, :limit => 15, :order => 'date desc'
   attr_accessible :symbol
   after_load :update_history

   #correct code is ( Thanks Dutow)
   after_initialize :update_history


   def update_history
      if (quotes.count > 0)
          today = Time.now
          get_and_store_history unless (quotes[0].updated_at >= today.beginning_of_day && quotes[0].updated_at <= today.end_of_day)
      end
   end

   def get_and_store_history
    #Update quotes
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord has a method called [after_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find), which is a callback like after_load.